# Non-zero potential measured on the surface of an insulator

Tags: electric-fields, voltage

After driving a screw into an alumina firebrick and applying a 5kV potential, I measured a ~4.5kV potential using a high voltage probe at other locations on the brick surface.

Firebrick is generally considered an insulator at room temperature. Using a mega-ohmmeter, we measured an ~2GigaOhm resistance along the length of the brick.

Treating the firebrick as a large resistor, we electrically grounded a second screw -- driven in to the opposite end of the first screw. In this case, no current flow was measured.

What would explain a high resistance element's small potential drop that isn't due to current flow?

Comment: Floating(induced) potentials should be the answer. The screw is a conductor so it acts like a capacitor. One plate being the screw, the other plate being the conductor itself. For the case of measurement, the instrument was to weak to show this phenomena. I'm not sure I interpreted your question right though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You present both a static and a quasi-static case here.  Let's consider them one at a time:

1) Static case: You applied a large potential to the screw relative to ground, which charged the screw.  The firebrick is a good insulator, but not perfect, so the charge on the screw should polarize the material slightly, creating a slight electric field inside the firebrick.  Potential is the integral of the field, so you see a small potential drop from the screw to other positions on the brick.

2) Quasi-static case: Again, the firebrick has high resistivity, but not infinite.  This means the conductivity is low, but not zero.  In this case the potential difference between the two screws is large, so the line integral of **E** between the screws is large.  Applying Ohm's law, **J** = c **E** where c is the conductivity.  Thus there is actually a very very tiny current flow between the screws (too small to be measured by your meter), and hence the voltage drop from the first screw to other locations.